# First-Time Indexing arrays is way too slow

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-4.0

I am writing an application using C#. I ran some benchmarks to try and speed up my application and came accross a problem. I have a loop which needs to run multiple times at separate intervals:

```
Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses();
foreach (Process process in processes)
    if (process.MainWindowTitle == "Title")
    {
        // Do Stuff
    }
```

I realized that the problem is, as soon as I create the array, accessing a specific element of that array takes significantly longer than subsequent access.

```
if (processes[0].MainWindowTitle == "Title") { } // ~0.5 ms
if (processes[0].MainWindowTitle == "Title") { } // ~0.0 ms
if (processes[0].MainWindowTitle == "Title") { } // ~0.0 ms
if (processes[0].MainWindowTitle == "Title") { } // ~0.0 ms
```

This is quite a significant problem. Something that should be taking less than 0.1ms is taking 50ms. Why is this happening and what can I can do to speed things up?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not accessing the array which is slow - it's getting the `MainWindowTitle` property, which I believe is lazily populated. When you first ask for it, it's doing all the OS gubbins to fetch the value.

To test this, try:

```
if (processes[0] != null)
```

which I think you'll find will be very fast right from the start.

Comment: Yeah, you're absolutely right. I was looking in the wrong place for my benchmarking. MainWindowTitle checks to see if it cached the title first, if it didn't it does some Native magic to get it which I guess is where its slowing down. Thanks.